# How to store only specific parts of a line, Java Linked Lists

Tags: java, linked-list

So, as the title states, I'm looking to store a bunch of different strings to a linked list. One thing that is true of all the values that need to go into a seperate list is that they all have the same denotative words at the beginning of the line, so is there some way that I can set up my scanner to look for those specific words, and then whatever is after that, store to the linked list?

Comment: What did you try already? Try to create it with code and post it here.

Comment: well, I tried at first to use the String.split() method to seperate the first part of the line from the second, then I went ahead and took the second half and threw it into the linkedlist, which is perfectly fine, but I'm trying to get to the point where I can do that for each line without having to hardcode it. I assume I would utilize a scanner to parse through and only do things on those lines, but I don't know how actually to go about doing it.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Where are these strings stored?

Comment: You need to step back and figure out what your requirement really is. "Store in a linked list" is not a requirement - it is a possible solution, and not necessarily a good one at that. What is it that you are really trying to accomplish? Why a linked list, rather than, for example, a map whose keys are the specific code words, and whose elements are each an ArrayList<String> containing the words following the key word?